# Use custom Transverse Mercator projection for poles

Tags: coordinate-system

Due to some reason (internal storage system), I want to define a custom Transverse Mercator projection for some parts of the world where the origin is nearby an area of interest.

But I also need to cover the poles, and as I said I want to stick to Transverse Mercator projection - if possible.

Is there any reason why I should use another projection like UPS instead?

Comment: Many TM implementations will only show part of the world. Do you need to show the entire arctic/antarctic area? If so, TM won't work.

Comment: I'm not showing anything on a map (which may sound weird, but it#s just stored for later use and conversion).

Comment: Do you need to have data around the poles for more than 90 or 180 degrees of longitude? AKA on the opposite side of the world. If so, I think TM won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If your main area of focus is the poles (or in the areas along the Y axis between the poles), I would recommend using a Spherical Transverse Mercator projection. It will preserve the shape and areas near the poles and along the Y axis, while distortion will increase along the x axis moving away from the poles.

[image: Spherical Transverse Mercator Projection]

Chapter 3 in the link below contains a lot more information on Transverse Mercator Projections centered on different points, depending on your area of study.

The Mercator Projections - Peter Osborne, Edinburgh, 2013:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130930144834/http://www.mercator99.webspace.virginmedia.com/mercator.pdf